# window.getSelection().toString() is not showing any value for dynamic data

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating online test system in `PHP` where i have put one question type where user select wrong question in text by clicking on it. The word background changes to red after mouse click on word.I use `window.getSelection().toString()` for that but i am not able to get the word. It was working very fine before but now alert is not showing any value.It is showing blank value. My code of html and javascript is showing below.

```
       <form method="post" name="test" action="student_result.php">
        <?php 
        $query_get_audio=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tps_questions where uid = $uid and question_type='audio'");
        $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_get_audio);
        ?>
        <div class="maindiv" >
         <div >
                    <audio controls id='myaudio' name='myaudio' class='myaudio' >
                      <source src="admin/<?php echo $row1 ['audio_file_loc']?>" type='audio/mpeg'>
                    </audio>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
        </div>
         <?php
         $query_get_uid=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tps_questions` WHERE `question_type` != 'audio' AND `uid` = $uid");
$counter=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_get_uid))
{
    $strqid=$strqid . "," .$row ['qid'];
    $strqtype=$strqtype . "," .$row ['question_type'];
    $strtime = $strtime . "," .$row ['timeDuration'];
    $qid = $row ['qid'];
    $quetype = $row['question_type']; 
    $quetime = $row['timeDuration'];
    $que = html_entity_decode($row['q_name']);
    $que = nl2br($que);
    if($counter==1)
    { 
        $pro="block";
    }
    else
    { 
        $pro="none";
    }
    if($quetype=="radio")
    {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tps_answers, tps_right_que_ans WHERE tps_answers.aid = tps_right_que_ans.aid AND qid ='$qid'");
    $row_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $aid = $row_res['aid'];
    $ans1 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans1']);
    $ans2 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans2']);
    $ans3 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans3']);
    $ans4 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans4']);
    echo "<div class='div" . $counter . "' style='display:" . $pro . ";' >
          <input type='hidden' name='qtype$counter' value = '$quetype'/>
          <input type='hidden' name='time$counter' value = '$quetime'/>
          <div >
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Que - $counter.) </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%'><input type='hidden' name='q$counter' value = '$qid'/>
                    <p>$que</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Ans : </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%;padding-bottom: 20px;'>
                    <label>a) <input id='radioans$counter" . "_1' type='radio' name='ans$counter' value='$ans1'/> $ans1</label><br>
                    <label>b) <input id='radioansq$counter" . "_2' type='radio' name='ans$counter' value='$ans2' /> $ans2</label><br>
                    <label>c) <input id='radioansq$counter" . "_3' type='radio' name='ans$counter' value='$ans3'/> $ans3</label><br>
                    <label>d) <input id='radioansq$counter" . "_4' type='radio' name='ans$counter' value='$ans4'/> $ans4</label><br>
                    <label>e) <input id='notattempt' type='radio' name='ans$counter' value='Not Attempted' checked='checked'/>Not Attempted</label><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>";
    }
    if($quetype=="fill")
    {
        $string="";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tps_answers, tps_right_que_ans WHERE tps_answers.aid = tps_right_que_ans.aid AND qid ='$qid'");

    $string= $string . "<div class='div" . $counter . "' style='display:" . $pro . ";' >
          <input type='hidden' name='qtype$counter' value = '$quetype'/>
          <input type='hidden' name='time$counter' value = '$quetime'/>
          <div >
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Que - $counter.) </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%'><input type='hidden' name='q$counter' value = '$qid'/>
                    <p>$que</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Ans : </div>
        <div style='float:left;width:80%;padding-bottom: 20px;'>" ;
        $val=1;
         while($row_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
         {
            $aid = $row_res['aid'];
            $ans1 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans1']);
            $ans2 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans2']);
            $ans3 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans3']);
            $ans4 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans4']);
            $string= $string . "

                        <label> <input id='radioans$counter" . "_1' type='radio' name='ans$val$counter' value='$ans1' checked='checked'/> $ans1</label>
                        <label> <input id='radioansq$counter" . "_2' type='radio' name='ans$val$counter' value='$ans2' /> $ans2</label>
                        <label> <input id='radioansq$counter" . "_3' type='radio' name='ans$val$counter' value='$ans3'/> $ans3</label>
                        <label> <input id='radioansq$counter" . "_4' type='radio' name='ans$val$counter' value='$ans4'/> $ans4</label><br>";
                        $val++;
         }
         $string= $string . "</div></div>";
         echo $string;
    }
    if($quetype=="text")
    {
        echo "<div class='div" . $counter . "' style='display:" . $pro . ";' >
         <input type='hidden' name='qtype$counter' value = '$quetype'/>
         <input type='hidden' name='time$counter' value = '$quetime'/>
        <div >
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Que - $counter.) </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%'><input type='hidden' name='q$counter' value = '$qid'/>
                    <p>$que</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Ans : </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%;padding-bottom: 20px;'>
                    <textarea name='textans$counter' id='textans$counter' class='textans$counter' cols='85%' rows='15%' wrap='off'></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>";
    }
    if($quetype=="jumble")
    {
        $input = array($row["A"], $row["B"], $row["C"],$row["D"]);
        shuffle($input);    //Shuffle function to shuffle the jumble answer comming from Database
        echo "<div class='div" . $counter . "' style='display:" . $pro . ";' >
         <input type='hidden' name='qtype$counter' value = '$quetype'/>
         <input type='hidden' name='time$counter' value = '$quetime'/>
        <div >
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Que - $counter.) </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%'><input type='hidden' name='q$counter' value = '$qid'/>
                    <p>$que</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Ans : </div>
            <div class='sortable' style='float:left;width:80%;padding-bottom: 20px;'>
              <div id='jumbleans$counter" . "_1' class='jumblediv'>" . $input[0] . "</div>
              <div id='jumbleans$counter" . "_2' class='jumblediv'>" . $input[1] . "</div>
              <div id='jumbleans$counter" . "_3' class='jumblediv'>" . $input[2] . "</div>
              <div id='jumbleans$counter" . "_4' class='jumblediv'>" . $input[3] . "</div>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>";
    }
    if($quetype=="drag_fill")
    {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tps_answers, tps_right_que_ans WHERE tps_answers.aid = tps_right_que_ans.aid AND qid ='$qid'");
    $row_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $aid = $row_res['aid'];
    $ans1 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans1']);
    $ans2 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans2']);
    $ans3 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans3']);
    $ans4 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans4']);
    $ans5 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans5']);
    $ans6 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans6']);
    $ans7 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans7']);
    $input = array($ans1,$ans2,$ans3,$ans4,$ans5,$ans6,$ans7);
    shuffle($input);
    echo "<div class='div" . $counter . "' style='display:" . $pro . ";' >
          <input type='hidden' name='qtype$counter' value = '$quetype'/>
          <div >
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Que - $counter.) </div>
            <div id='question' style='float:left;width:80%'><input type='hidden' name='q$counter' value = '$qid'/>
                    <p>$que</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Ans : </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%;padding:20px;background:lightblue;margin-bottom:10px;' id='answer'>
                    <label style='padding:20px;background:#ededed'>" . $input[0] . "</label>
                    <label style='padding:20px;background:#ededed'>" . $input[1] . "</label>
                    <label style='padding:20px;background:#ededed'>" . $input[2] . "</label>
                    <label style='padding:20px;background:#ededed'>" . $input[3] . "</label>
                    <label style='padding:20px;background:#ededed'>" . $input[4] . "</label>
                    <label style='padding:20px;background:#ededed'>" . $input[5] . "</label>
                    <label style='padding:20px;background:#ededed'>" . $input[6] . "</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>";
    }

    if($quetype=="checkbox")
    {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tps_answers, tps_right_que_ans WHERE tps_answers.aid = tps_right_que_ans.aid AND qid ='$qid'");
    $row_res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $aid = $row_res['aid'];
    $chkans1 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans1']);
    $chkans2 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans2']);
    $chkans3 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans3']);
    $chkans4 = htmlspecialchars($row_res['ans4']);
    echo "<div class='div" . $counter . "' style='display:" . $pro . ";' >
          <input type='hidden' name='qtype$counter' value = '$quetype'/>
          <input type='hidden' name='time$counter' value = '$quetime'/>
          <div >
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Que - $counter.) </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%'><input type='hidden' name='q$counter' value = '$qid'/>
                    <p>$que</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Ans : </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%;padding-bottom: 20px;'>
                    <label>a) <input id='chkans$counter" . "_1' type='checkbox' name='chkans$counter" . "_1' value='$chkans1'/> $chkans1</label><br>
                    <label>b) <input id='chkans$counter" . "_2' type='checkbox' name='chkans$counter" . "_2' value='$chkans2' /> $chkans2</label><br>
                    <label>c) <input id='chkans$counter" . "_3' type='checkbox' name='chkans$counter" . "_3' value='$chkans3'/> $chkans3</label><br>
                    <label>d) <input id='chkans$counter" . "_4' type='checkbox' name='chkans$counter" . "_4' value='$chkans4'/> $chkans4</label><br>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>";
    }
    if($quetype=="write-answer")
    {
        echo "<div class='div" . $counter . "' style='display:" . $pro . ";' >
         <input type='hidden' name='qtype$counter' value = '$quetype'/>
         <input type='hidden' name='time$counter' value = '$quetime'/>
        <div >
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Que - $counter.) </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%'><input type='hidden' name='q$counter' value = '$qid'/>
                    <p>$que</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>";
    }
    if($quetype=="pick-wrong")
    {
        echo "<div class='div" . $counter . "' style='display:" . $pro . ";' >
         <input type='hidden' name='qtype$counter' value = '$quetype'/>
         <input type='hidden' name='time$counter' value = '$quetime'/>
        <div >
            <div style='float:left;width:20%'>Que - $counter.) </div>
            <div style='float:left;width:80%' ><input type='hidden' name='q$counter' value = '$qid'/>
                    <p id='pickWrongText'>$que</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>";
    }
    $counter++;
}
if($counter==1)
{
    $msg = "No Test is Available or Test is OFF.";
    session_destroy();
    echo "<script>setTimeout(function() {window.location.href= 'index.php';},4000);</script>";
}
$chars = "1234567890";
$resid = "";
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
    $rand_user = rand() % strlen ($chars);
    $temp_user = substr($chars,$rand_user,1);
    $resid .= $temp_user; 
}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='unit' value='$uid'/>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='lid' value='1'/>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='resid' value='$resid'/>";
$counter--;
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='counter' value='$counter' />"
    ?>
    <label class="col-lg-6" ><?php echo "<h2>" . $msg . "</h2>"; ?></label>
   <div align="right"><button class="button" id="next" type="button" name="next" >Next</button></div>
   <div ><input class="button" id="finish" type="submit" name="finish_test" value="Save & View Test" style="display:none;" /></div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="data_fetch"></div>
   </div>   <!-- End of main div -->
```

**Javascript Code:-**

```
     function get_selection() 
       {
          var txt = '';
          var flag=0;
          var seltext='';
          alert(window.getSelection().toString());
          if(window.getSelection) {
                txt = window.getSelection().toString();
          } else if(document.selection) {
                txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
          }
          var tr = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
          var span = document.createElement("span");
          if(flag==0)
          {

                        span.style.cssText = "background:#ff0000;color:#ffffff";
                        flag=1;
                        //alert("+ve" + flag);
        }
        else if(flag==1)
        {
                    span.style.cssText = "color:#000000";   
                        flag=0;   
        }
            tr.surroundContents(span);
}

    document.getElementById("pickWrongText").onclick = get_selection;
```

Comment: Could you provide the relevant html code also?

Comment: I change the html.Kindly see to it and give me answer.It is very urgent please.

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to alert? what is window.getSelection().toString() supposed to be?

Comment: Did you figure it out?